# Emulating inline variables in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, static-initialization

In a header-only library, I need to run some initialization code before using any library functionality. At the moment, I have an explicit `init()` function for this purpose that the user needs to call explicitly.

I would like to avoid forcing the user to remember to call such a function. A partial solution is to embed the init logic in an object constructor, and then store an instance of such object as static member in a class template:

```
struct initializer {
    initializer()
    {
        // init() logic here.
    }
};

template <typename = void>
struct holder {
    static initializer s_init;
};

template <typename T>
initializer holder<T>::s_init;
```

The problem with such a solution is that, in order for the `s_init` member to be actually constructed at runtime, the `holder` class template needs to be instantiated.

My question then is this: is it enough to define an `inline` function for the purpose of triggering the instantiation of the `holder` object? I.e., something like

```
inline void trigger_instantiation()
{
    auto init = holder<>::s_init;
}
```

to be included in all the headers of the library?

Comment: No, it's not. This is [an obvious XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the real problem you're trying to solve. No, not the one you asked here, but the real problem whose solution you think is what you're asking here.

Comment: Recent clang supports inline variables, doesn't it.

Comment: How about having a class which you create a `static` instance, and whose constructor is using [`std::call_once`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/call_once) to call the initialization function? Even if it's instantiated multiple times (because you include the header file multipe times), the [`std::call_once`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/call_once) ensures the initialization function will only be called once.

Comment: @DeiDei I need a solution which works in C++11.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I don't understand. Are you complaining that I added context about my question? Would you like me to reword my question to something like "is this a somewhat acceptable replacement for inline variables in C++11"?

Comment: [Nifty counter](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Nifty_Counter), perhaps? That's how `std::cin` et al usually get instantiated and initialized.

Comment: You can make a configuration object a static member of an inline function to guarantee its initialization before first use: `inline config& get_config() { static config cfg; return cfg; }` Then any library functions that need the config call `get_config()` to retrieve it.

Comment: Look at `ios_base::Init` for some inspiration.

Comment: @Galik thanks, but this is not a configuration object, it a bunch of logic that needs to be executed before accessing the library's functionality. I have no need to access the initialization object after it has been created.

Comment: @bluescarni I think it could be useful to give more information on what your library is about, what type of API it has for the user (so maybe you could hook the init there), and what type of logic needs to be done during initialization. Maybe there's an alternative way to initialization that can only be seen if you give a comprehensive view of the problem.